# How to create an exception for third-party cookies in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, cookies

Both IE and Firefox allow you to block third-party cookies.  In Firefox the option this option is under Privacy tab in Options dialog.
IE browser allows users to set up an exceptions.  For example I can block all third-party cookies except for www.mysite.com.

Is there a way to create the same exception in Firefox?

Comment: In later versions of Firefox first select option "Use custom settings for history" in the dropdown for "Firefox will:" to be able to set third-party cookies options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the extension [CookieSafe](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2497):

> This extension will allow you to
>   easily control cookie permissions. It
>   will appear on your statusbar. Just
>   click on the icon to allow, block, or
>   temporarily allow the site to set
>   cookies. You can also view or clear
>   the cookies and exceptions by...

Edit: The extension CookieSafe has now been retired.

Comment: I installed CookieSafe but unfortunately it didn't give me control of third-party cookies I'd like to have.  Thanks you for this idea it definitely was worth to try.

Comment: @Vadim, did you notice that you can click-right and also left-click on the icon, giving different menus? It would surprise me to find that there's anything at all that CookieSafe can't do ...

Answer (score 8):

You can put your site under the Exception button and it should work. I have done a similar thing and it's working for me.

Comment: This works without installing anything. Not to mention that the extension mentioned above is still not available for FF4

Comment: Nowadays you can just use the built-in controls to block all third party cookies, but allow some under Privacy -> History/Cookies -> Exceptions.